# ESP8266-01 Serial.print returns a blank given a valid string

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, c

I am currently trying to create a led matrix with ws2812b leds. I am using an uno on the rear of the display to control the leds and now I want to add wifi capabilities. Since I already had serial control implemented into the uno, I decided to use an ESP8266-01 to take wifi commands and then send them via serial to the uno. The problem is that no matter what I send to the ESP, it always prints a blank to to the uno.

The code for the ESP:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>


// config: ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#define UART_BAUD 9600

#define MODE_AP // phone connects directly to ESP
//#define MODE_STA // ESP connects to WiFi router

#define PROTOCOL_TCP
//#define PROTOCOL_UDP


#ifdef MODE_AP
// For AP mode:
const char *ssid = "LedSign";  // You will connect your phone to this Access Point
const char *pw = "aaron"; // and this is the password
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 1); // From RoboRemo app, connect to this IP
IPAddress netmask(255, 255, 255, 0);
const int port = 6969; // and this port
// You must connect the phone to this AP, then:
// menu -> connect -> Internet(TCP) -> 192.168.0.1:9876
#endif



boolean led = false; 

String message;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




#ifdef PROTOCOL_TCP
#include <WiFiClient.h>
WiFiServer server(port);
WiFiClient client;
#endif



void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

  delay(500);

  Serial.begin(UART_BAUD);

  #ifdef MODE_AP 
  //AP mode (phone connects directly to ESP) (no router)
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, ip, netmask); // configure ip address for softAP 
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, pw); // configure ssid and password for softAP
  #endif


  #ifdef PROTOCOL_TCP
  Serial.println("Starting TCP Server");
  server.begin(); // start TCP server 
  #endif

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    Serial.println("Booting up");
    delay(100);
  }

}


void loop() {

  #ifdef PROTOCOL_TCP
  if(!client.connected()) { // if client not connected
    client = server.available(); // wait for it to connect
    if (led){
      pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
      led = false;
      delay(100);
    }
    else
    {
      pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
      led = true;
      delay(100);
    }
    return;

  }

  // here we have a connected client

  if(client.available()) {
    String message;
    long time = millis();
    Serial.println("Message Recieved: ");
    while(client.available()) {
      message = client.readStringUntil('\n'); // read char from client (RoboRemo app)
      message.trim();
      //message+=c;
      if (millis()-time >= 200)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    client.print("You typed: ");
    client.println(message);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
    delay(400);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
    delay(400);
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,LOW);
    // now send to UART:
    delay(10);
    message.trim();
    message = message + '-';
    Serial.println(message);
    //Serial.println(message);
  }
  /*
  if(Serial.available()) {

    // read the data until pause:

    while(1) {
      if(Serial.available()) {
        buf2[i2] = (char)Serial.read(); // read char from UART
        if(i2<bufferSize-1) i2++;
      } else {
        //delayMicroseconds(packTimeoutMicros);
        delay(packTimeout);
        if(!Serial.available()) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    */
    // now send to WiFi:
    //client.write((char*)buf2, i2);
    //i2 = 0;
  //}
  #endif




}
```

The code for the uno (just for testing functionality of ESP, no leds):

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if(Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    String message = Serial.readStringUntil('-');
    message.trim();
    Serial.print("The message was: ");
    Serial.println(message);
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);

    if (message.equals("h"))
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
        delay(50);
        digitalWrite(13,LOW);
        delay(50);
      }
    }
    Serial.flush();
  }

}
```

I have confirmed that the ESP is reading the data from TCP by having it print the string back at me. I know that the ESP is attempting to send the data because the led blinks indicating it triggered the if statement. I know that the uno is getting something over serial becasue the serial lights flash, the builtin led flashes (my code), and the uno prints back what it got to serial (though that is just a blank).

What the uno prints /

```
14:15:03.495 -> The message was:
```

I am at my wits end with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you print the String "The message was: " on the UNO, where do you read it? On your serial terminal? But then the Serial port is connected with the terminal over USB and also to the ESP via the pins 0 and 1. I fear that can not work. You can not connect two endpoints to the same serial port.  As the UNO has only 1 hardware serial. You have to use a SoftwareSerial to communicate with the ESP. Or you do not use the connection to the serial terminal on the PC. And access the returned string over the network connection by reading from serial on the ESB..

Comment: Yeah using software serial was a good point although that did not appear to be the issue. Is there anything else that this could be? I am still getting the same serial result on my computer.

Comment: Yes, there are more issues. But I must know, how you implemented the SoftwareSerial solution before I can give you an answer. I don't know which problems you has been solved with that solution.

Comment: I fixed the problem. My baud rates were mismatched. Thanks for the help.